# Fieldset next to floated div overflows to the right in chrome/IE, breaks to the next line in FF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3. 
I have a containing element containing a floated div and a fieldset. The floated div is 100% width so the fieldset should sit below it. This works in FF (which I was using to develop) but in chrome/IE, the fieldset overflows out of container and sits to the right of `float`.

[image]

```css
.container{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.float{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div style="float:left;width:100%;">
        <a >Select All</a> / <a >Select None</a>
    </div>
    <fieldset>fieldset</fieldset>
</div>
```

I can fix it by adding `clear:left;` to the fieldset.

Which browser is correct? It seems like FF is in the wrong. What rule is FF breaking or excepting to cause this to render differently? Is this a bug?

Noting that when not using bootstrap, it renders as expected in all browsers I tested. Within bootstrap, if I use a div instead of a fieldset, it also renders the same across browsers.

Comment: Just use "pull-left" in fieldset also. it will work in all the browsers. Then you dont have to add "clear" class also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's the `fieldset` default styling being over-ridden by the Bootstrap CSS. It's applying a `min-width: 0` to `fieldset` which is causing the element to have no width. Not sure why this was added to Bootstrap but it's probably something to do with it's [expected content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) being actual form fields as opposed to just text as per your example. Try adding some valid form HTML as per the MDN link to see if that improves your situation.

Comment: the thing I posted is a minimal example, my fieldset does have form elements in it, its a bunch of checkboxes

Comment: Look into the Bootstrap documentation for how to use fieldset in form elements. You might be missing a class or two. Appreciate you want to be brief on here but it's better to paste up all your code so we get the full picture :)

Comment: I guess I should just be using a div here